# jquery - form validation breaks ajax post

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

I have a registration page and I am posting the data to a php page using Ajax. I have form validation as follows:

```
firstname = $("#firstname").val();
if(firstname === '') {
    $("#error").empty().append("Please enter a first name.");
    $("#firstname").css("border-color", "#FF5454");
    return false;
}
```

I submit the variable in an Ajax post as below:

```
jQuery.ajax({
type: "POST",
url: "/includes/register_process.php",
data:'gender=' + gender + '&firstname=' + firstname + '&surname=' + surname
+ '&studentno=' + studentno + '&email=' + email + '&password=' + password
+ '&confirmpwd=' + confirmpwd,
etc etc.
```

I wanted to change the validation above as follows:

```
firstname = $("#firstname").val();
if(firstname === '') {
    $("#error").empty().append("Please enter a first name.");
    $("#firstname").css("border-color", "#FF5454");
    return false;
} else {
    $("#error").hide();
    $("#firstname").css("border-color", "#4DC742");
    return true;
}
```

This seems to break the Ajax post as it doesn't seem to post the data to the php page.

Could anyone give me some hints on why that change makes the Ajax post not work? I am a beginner in using Ajax.

Thanks.

EDIT 1:

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function() {
$("#FormSubmit").click(function (event) {
event.preventDefault();

gender = $('#gender option:selected').val();
if (gender === 'null') {
    $("#error").empty().append("Please select a gender.");
    $("#gender").css("border-color", "#FF5454");
    return false;
} else {
    $("#error").hide();
    $("#gender").css("border-color", "#4DC742");
    return true;
}

firstname = $("#firstname").val();
if(firstname === '') {
    $("#error").empty().append("Please enter a first name.");
    $("#firstname").css("border-color", "#FF5454");
    return false;
}

surname = $("#surname").val();
if(surname === '') {
    $("#error").empty().append("Please enter a surname.");
    $("#surname").css("border-color", "#FF5454");
    return false;
}

studentno = $("#studentno").val();
if(studentno === '') {
    $("#error").empty().append("Please enter a student number.");
    $("#studentno").css("border-color", "#FF5454");
    return false;
}

email = $("#email").val();
if(email === '') {
    $("#error").empty().append("Please enter an e-mail address.");
    $("#email").css("border-color", "#FF5454");
    return false;
}

password = $("#password").val();
if(password === '') {
    $("#error").empty().append("Please enter a password.");
    $("#password").css("border-color", "#FF5454");
    return false;
}

if (password.length < 6) {
    $(".sad-feedback").empty().append("Passwords must be at least 6 characters long. Please try again.");
    $("#password").css("border-color", "#FF5454");
    return false;
}

confirmpwd = $("#confirmpwd").val();
if(confirmpwd === '') {
    $("#error").empty().append("Please enter a password confirmation.");
    $("#confirmpwd").css("border-color", "#FF5454");
    return false;
}

if(password != confirmpwd) {
    $(".sad-feedback").empty().append("Your password and confirmation do not match. Please try again.");
    $("#password").css("border-color", "#FF5454");
    $("#confirmpwd").css("border-color", "#FF5454");
    return false;
}

jQuery.ajax({
type: "POST",
url: "/includes/register_process.php",
data:'gender=' + gender + '&firstname=' + firstname + '&surname=' + surname + '&studentno=' + studentno + '&email=' + email + '&password=' + password + '&confirmpwd=' + confirmpwd,
success:function(response){
    $("#hide").hide();
    $("#register-button").hide();
    $("#FormSubmit").hide();
    $("#error").hide();
    $("#success").append('Thank you for your registration. You can now sign in to your account.');
    $("#success-button").show();
},
error:function (xhr, ajaxOptions, thrownError){
    $("#error").empty().append(thrownError);
}
});

});
});
</script>
```

EDIT 2:

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function() {
$("#FormSubmit").click(function (e) {
e.preventDefault();

var hasError = false;

gender = $('#gender option:selected').val();
if (gender === 'null') {
    $("#error").empty().append("Please select a gender.");
    $("#gender").css("border-color", "#FF5454");
    hasError  = true;
} else {
    $("#error").hide();
    $("#gender").css("border-color", "#4DC742");
    hasError  = false;
}

firstname = $("#firstname").val();
if(firstname === '') {
    $("#error").show();
    $("#error").empty().append("Please enter a first name.");
    $("#firstname").css("border-color", "#FF5454");
    hasError  = true;
} else {
    $("#error").hide();
    $("#firstname").css("border-color", "#4DC742");
    hasError  = false;
}

surname = $("#surname").val();
if(surname === '') {
    $("#error").show();
    $("#error").empty().append("Please enter a surname.");
    $("#surname").css("border-color", "#FF5454");
    hasError  = true;
} else {
    $("#error").hide();
    $("#surname").css("border-color", "#4DC742");
    hasError  = false;
}

studentno = $("#studentno").val();
if(studentno === '') {
    $("#error").show();
    $("#error").empty().append("Please enter a student number.");
    $("#studentno").css("border-color", "#FF5454");
    hasError  = true;
} else {
    $("#error").hide();
    $("#studentno").css("border-color", "#4DC742");
    hasError  = false;
}

email = $("#email").val();
if(email === '') {
    $("#error").show();
    $("#error").empty().append("Please enter an e-mail address.");
    $("#email").css("border-color", "#FF5454");
    hasError  = true;
} else {
    $("#error").hide();
    $("#email").css("border-color", "#4DC742");
    hasError  = false;
}

password = $("#password").val();
if(password === '') {
    $("#error").show();
    $("#error").empty().append("Please enter a password.");
    $("#password").css("border-color", "#FF5454");
    hasError  = true;
} else {
    $("#error").hide();
    $("#password").css("border-color", "#4DC742");
    hasError  = false;
}

if (password.length < 6) {
    $("#error").show();
    $(".sad-feedback").empty().append("Passwords must be at least 6 characters long. Please try again.");
    $("#password").css("border-color", "#FF5454");
    hasError  = true;
} else {
    $("#error").hide();
    $("#password").css("border-color", "#4DC742");
    hasError  = false;
}

confirmpwd = $("#confirmpwd").val();
if(confirmpwd === '') {
    $("#error").show();
    $("#error").empty().append("Please enter a password confirmation.");
    $("#confirmpwd").css("border-color", "#FF5454");
    hasError  = true;
} else {
    $("#error").hide();
    $("#confirmpwd").css("border-color", "#4DC742");
    hasError  = false;
}

if(password != confirmpwd) {
    $("#error").show();
    $(".sad-feedback").empty().append("Your password and confirmation do not match. Please try again.");
    $("#password").css("border-color", "#FF5454");
    $("#confirmpwd").css("border-color", "#FF5454");
    hasError  = true;
} else {
    $("#error").hide();
    $("#confirmpwd").css("border-color", "#4DC742");
    hasError  = false;
}

if(hasError == false){
jQuery.ajax({
type: "POST",
url: "http://test.student-portal.co.uk/includes/register_process.php",
data:'gender=' + gender + '&firstname=' + firstname + '&surname=' + surname + '&studentno=' + studentno + '&email=' + email + '&password=' + password + '&confirmpwd=' + confirmpwd,
success:function(response){
    $("#hide").hide();
    $("#register-button").hide();
    $("#FormSubmit").hide();
    $("#error").hide();
    $("#success").append('Thank you for your registration. You can now sign in to your account.');
    $("#success-button").show();
},
error:function (xhr, ajaxOptions, thrownError){
    $("#error").show();
    $("#error").empty().append(thrownError);
}
});
}

return true;

});
});
</script>
```

Comment: Have you checked your browser console to see if there are any js errors / messages?

Comment: Yeah, there are no errors/messages at all.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the problem here is that you are returning from the closure in the first check itself

```
event.preventDefault();
gender = $('#gender option:selected').val();
if (gender === 'null') {
    $("#error").empty().append("Please select a gender.");
    $("#gender").css("border-color", "#FF5454");
    return false;// no need to return 
} else {
    $("#error").hide();
    $("#gender").css("border-color", "#4DC742");
    return true;// No need to return 
}
```

So the  ajax call never gets called. You should instead set a boolean value may be call it hasError or something and set its value based on your validations. Then at the end of the closure make the ajax call or don't make the call based on the value of hasError

So example consider doing this .

```
...
event.preventDefault();
var hasError = false;
$("#error").empty();// Empty out the  errors container first
gender = $('#gender option:selected').val();
if (gender === null) {

    $("#error").append("Please select a gender.<br/>");// Changes here remove the empty
    $("#gender").css("border-color", "#FF5454");
    hasError  = true;
} else {

    $("#gender").css("border-color", "#4DC742");
    // EDIT : hasError =  false; remove this line
} ..... // All  the other validation
```

Then on the bottom

```
if(hasError == false){
   $("#error").hide();
   // Make the ajax call
} else {
   $("#error").show();
}

return true; // we handled the event
```

Hope that helps

Comment: Thanks for this. If I remove the return false; on the validation, the validation doesn't work, it seems like they all get triggered at the same time.

Comment: Based on your code things are triggered at the same time and you only have #error to place your error messages in so you will only get the last error (or rather hide the #error)  based on the last if else condition

Comment: Edited my post with the new code. I am showing and hiding the errors. When I was using the return false; it seemed like it was taking them one by one in order. Also, looking at the console, it seems like now the ajax request just gets executed without following the validation bit as it brings up error messages from the php page.

Comment: I have made the some changes in the answer so that you get all the error messages of your validation displayed instead of  just the last one. Have a look

Comment: Edited the code . Remove the hasError = false on the validation success.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
$(document).on("submit", "form", function(event)//Try to set id of the form and use it #from_id instead of form
{
    event.preventDefault();

    //now call your ajax
     jQuery.ajax({
      type: "POST",
      url: "/includes/register_process.php",
      data:'gender=' + gender + '&firstname=' + firstname + '&surname=' + surname
      + '&studentno=' + studentno + '&email=' + email + '&password=' + password
      + '&confirmpwd=' + confirmpwd,
      etc etc.

});
```

Comment: @Sergiu Tripon you are using click event. Use submit event and id should be form id

Comment: one more thing use full path instead of relative path `/includes/register_process.php`